# firebase retrieve data using orderByChild() and equalTo()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Example my db firebase]

```
firebase.database().ref('requests')
  .orderByChild('sender')
  .equalTo("viePatHR0qRaBPGvsb992LEM55F3")
  .on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.key);})
```

So I'm trying to find the key node under "requests" in the picture: (example: `Mt8ElzJCDfSwDgdjjLuu38KUSw83` and `e3iFEuoTtJXAkLgOyxoT0LIeQAg1`)
I used this code, But I got nothing back. What was wrong? What should I use?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Answer (score 3):

The `.orderByChild` query only works on the child level. (no grandchilds) In your case this would be the level with the firebase push-keys e.g. `-KwqBYHP...`

So if you do `.orderByChild('sender')` it will not work, since there is no property called `sender` on this level.

So you have two options depending on your case. If `viePatHR0qRaBPGvsb992LEM55F3` is a unique id you can get rid of the firebase pushkeys by using `set` instead of `push` to save your data to the database.

If `viePatHR0qRaBPGvsb992LEM55F3` is no unique id, then you need to modify your reference.

The modified reference would look like this `firebase.database().ref('requests/viePatHR0qRaBPGvsb992LEM55F3').orderByChild('sender')`

If this is not what you expect, the only option you have is to rebuild your data structure. Getting rid of the deep nesting by creating for example a property called:

`id: "viePatHR0qRaBPGvsb992LEM55F3"`

directly on your object (on the same level where the `sender` property is).